# glibc - force function call (no inline expansion)

Tags: c, gcc, inline, glibc

I have a question regarding glibc function calls. Is there a flag to tell gcc not to inline a certain glibc function, e.g. memcpy?

I've tried -fno-builtin-memcpy and other flags, but they didn't work. The goal is that the actual glibc memcpy function is called and no inlined code (since the glibc version at compile time differs from the one at runtime). It's for testing purposes only. Normally I wan't do that.

Any solutions?

UPDATE:

Just to make it clearer: In the past memcpy works even with overlapping areas. This has changed meanwhile and I can see this changes when compiling with different glibc versions. So now I want to test if my old code (using memcpy where memmove should have been used) works correct or not on a system with a newer glibc (e.g. 2.14). But to do that, I have to make sure, that the new memcpy is called and no inlined code.

Best regards

Comment: rewrite `memcpy(params..)` into `(memcpy)(params..)`

Comment: @osgx: That prevents expansion of any `memcpy()` macro, but it doesn't affect inlining of actual functions.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it seems to force gcc to generate an *indirect* call to `memcpy()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)

unsigned int x = 0xdeadbeef;
unsigned int y;

int main(void) {
    void *(*memcpy_ptr)(void *, const void *, size_t) = memcpy;
    if (time(NULL) == 1) {
        memcpy_ptr = NULL;
    }
    memcpy_ptr(&y, &x, sizeof y);
    printf("y = 0x%x\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

The generated assembly (gcc, Ubuntu, x86) includes a `call *%edx` instruction.

Without the `if (time(NULL) == 1)` test (which should never succeed, but the compiler doesn't know that), `gcc -O3` is clever enough to recognize that the indirect call always calls `memcpy()`, which can then be replaced by a `movl` instruction.

Note that the compiler *could* recognize that if `memcpy_ptr == NULL` then the behavior is undefined, and again replace the indirect call with a direct call, and then with a `movl` instruction.  gcc 4.5.2 with `-O3` doesn't appear to be that clever.  If a later version of `gcc` is, you could replace the `memcpy_ptr = NULL` with an assignment of some actual function that behaves differently than `memcpy()`.

Comment: @user1169333: Ok, what exactly is the desired effect?  Why does an indirect call not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

In theory:

```
gcc -fno-inline -fno-builtin-inline ...
```

But then you said `-fno-builtin-memcpy` didn't stop the compiler from inlining it, so there's no obvious reason why this should work any better.

Comment: According the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) the `-fno-inline` applies to ignoring the `inline` keyword in the source code. I believe the desired parameter is `-fno-inline-functions` combined with [`-fno-builtin`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options). I checked using `nm` rather than checking the interrupt calls in the assembly source code.

Comment: With -fno-inline-functions and -fno-builtin the binary becomes smaller so the flags had an effect but not on the result of the program (as I would expect).

Answer (score 0):

```
#undef memcpy
#define mempcy your_memcpy_replacement
```

Somewhere at the top but after #include  obviously

And mark your_memcpy_replacement as **attribute**((noinline))